# Statistical softwares providing multiple seasonality forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multiple-seasonalities

Does anybody know which software provide forecasting with more than two seasonalities? I know R includes tools for double seasonal holt winter forecasting but I am looking for a software which can forecast triple seasonal data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bats` function in the `forecast` package in R. References and explanation [here](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/complex-seasonality/).

Comment: I tried it but it did not provide me with good forecast. I first used dshw which gave me a pretty good model with very small errors. but using bats, it gave me totally off forecasts.

Comment: That seems strange to me. `bats` in its simplest form is akin to tshw. I might suggest posting your data, along with what you've tried so far, as a *new* question.

Comment: dshw is a special case of bats/tbats. you are doing something incorrect with your modeling or your dataset has no pattern